# migrated questions appear under `active` but not `newest`?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

Just had my question migrated from stackoverflow, but couldn't find the question anywhere until I looked in `active`. Shouldn't the question also appear in `newest`?

Comment: Please don't migrate basic support questions/bug reports to Meta Stack Overflow. There's no need. We monitor all child metas already, and the question was raised within this community, so shuffling it over serves little purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Migration counts as the "latest activity" on a question, which drops the question in the active feed and shows it on the front page.

The *age* of the question is still whatever it actually is based on the timestamp set when you posted it. So your question does show up under "newest" in its appropriate chronological spot. (As I'm writing this, it's on page 5.)